# Why are constrctor() and ngOnInit() not added to the component code in Angular 14?

Tags: angular

I'm following a bit outdated tutorial as an intro to Angular (https://www.udemy.com/course/angular-for-beginners-course/learn/lecture/12538306#overview). It is using some older Angular version.
I'm a total noob in Angular.

Upon creating a custom component, in the that older version of Angular that the course is using, there is a constructor() and ngOnInit(), that are not present in Angular 14. Are they deprecated or somehow used elsewhere, or simply not generated by Angular CLI automatically anymore? What is the reason for this difference in the generated component code?

Here the code:
(Angular 14)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'course-card',
  templateUrl: './course-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-card.component.css']
})
export class CourseCardComponent {

}
```

(older version)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'course-card',
  templateUrl: './course-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-card.component.css']
})
export class CourseCardComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }
ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Angular CLI: 14** `ng version | ng v` upon executing `ng g c test` to generate a component named "test" the output has expected `constructor` and `ngOnInit()`.

As of **Angular CLI 15** `ng g c test` no longer includes `constructor` and `ngOnInit()` in the default generation output.

Whether this change is good or bad, time will tell. To generate `constructor` and `ngOnInit()` with components you'd have to modify schematics or downgrade to Angular CLI 14.

Here's the recap:

https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2022/11/16/angular-cli-15.0/

https://indepth.dev/posts/1508/structure-initialization-logic-without-ngoninit-utilize-observables-and-ngonchanges

Comment: Thanks! and for the links as well :) That's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`constructor` is a part of Typescript, and `ngOnInit()` is still valid component lifecycle hook.

Neither of those are mandatory (now and in older versions of angular) in order for `componen`t to work and some `lint` configurations (maybe even the default one provided with the skeleton app) yelds an error for empty method definitions.

I guess this is the reason (both beeing non mandatory).

Answer (score 1):

The `constructor` and `ngOnInit` were removed from generated component, because Angular programmers (including myself) preferred to add these only when needed. They are not deprecated.

See the [pull request removing it](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/24008).

Answer (score 1):

As time goes by , angular versions get updated and so components generated no longer have constructor and ngOnInit in the newer versions of Angular. I suspect this was done to crunch down on boilerplate code seeing as you only need to use them when you are doing dependency injection and lifecycle hooking. Other than that, they are not deprecated at all.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that many devs have doubts about removing ngOnInit() but find it reasonable to remove the constructor. In my experience, I have primarily used the constructor for Dependency Injection (DI), which can now be accomplished using the inject() method provided by Angular. This approach is considered superior to constructor-based DI in most cases.

using constructor()

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-using-constructor',
      templateUrl: './using-constructor.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./using-constructor.component.scss']
    })
    export class UsingConstructorComponent {
        constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
      }
    }
```

using inject()

```
 import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
 import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-using-inject',
      templateUrl: './using-inject.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./using-inject.component.scss']
    })
    export class UsingInjectComponent {
          private messageService = inject(MessageService);
    }
```